# powershellv2 - how to sort a list after splitting the string

Tags: sorting, powershell, powershell-2.0

I have a file containing a list of email addresses:

e.g.

```
personB@placeB.com
nameA@location2.com
nameB@location2.com
```

I want to order them, but by the domain, and then by the local, and then output the ordered list. so I end up with:

```
nameA@location2.com
nameB@location2.com
personB@placeB.com
```

I can use `sort-object` to order them, but this is by the whole string.

So far I have got this far:

```
SELECT-STRING -path path_To_My_File |
FOREACH{
    $a = $_.split"(@)"
    $local = $a[0]
    $domain = $a[1]
}
```

but can't see how to incorporate the `sort-object`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Similar to Matt's answer, but will give you the sorted email addresses as a list:

```powershell
$addresses = @()

Get-Content .\path\to\file | % {
  $n = $($_ -split '@')[0]
  $d = $($_ -split '@')[1]
  $o = New-Object PSObject -property @{name=$n;domain=$d;email=$_}
  $addresses += ,$o
}

$addresses | sort domain,name | select -ExpandProperty email
```

The `$addresses` array can be sorted by the object you created on the fly in the `Foreach-Object` or `%` loop, and then you can just select the `email` property to give you the sorted list

Comment: Cheers for that, it works just how I wanted. the ultimate aim would be to pipe it into a file at the end. So this should be perfect

Answer (score 4):

`Sort-Object` obviously needs an object to sort on. So we can create an object like this. ( There are other ways as well). Also we dont need to use `select-string` since you are applying no patterns

```
Get-Content -path "path_To_My_File" | 
Select-Object @{Name="Local";Expression={($_.split("@"))[0]}},@{Name="Domain";Expression={($_.split("@"))[1]}} | 
Sort-Object domain,local
```

Create properties using `Select-Object` for `Local` and `Domain` using the same split that you had. The select on its own would output this:

```
Local           Domain                                                            
-----           ------                                                            
personB         placeB.com                                                        
nameA           location2.com                                                     
nameB           location2.com
```

Then we can sort to get this:

```
Local           Domain                                                            
-----           ------                                                            
nameA           location2.com                                                     
nameB           location2.com                                                     
personB         placeB.com
```

If you need the full address as well we can shorten the code and add that variable.

```
Get-Content -path "path_To_My_File" | 
    Select  @{N="Address";E={$_}},
            @{N="Local";E={($_.split("@"))[0]}},
            @{N="Domain";E={($_.split("@"))[1]}} | 
    Sort domain,local
```

Comment: Cheers for that, I never thought about creating my own object.